# can we directly migrate Struts from Struts 2.0 to Struts 2.5?

Tags: struts2, migration

I am currently using `Struts 2.0` version in my project. Now I want to move the `Struts 2.5` version for the same. Can I directly move from `2.0 to 2.5`?

1. If yes what things we need to change?
2. If no how can we achieve it? want detailed steps.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide a specific question and explain what you are having problems with. Phrases like "how can we achieve it, want details steps" will not get you any answers. See also here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: means how can we migrate it step by step. which tags need to change.

Comment: Again, please read the "how to ask" link. SO is not a "show me how to do this" website.